# How do I select continuously table <td> element onhover() cursor pointer in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my scenario, if I start selecting table  element Jan 01, Feb 01, Mar 01 continuously to Apri 01, Apri 02, Mar 02, Feb 02.

It selects table  then change class to "cellselect" and selected  element "datavalselet" val add in one array i.e  
$scope.selectedCell = [] and
unselect  element value add in  $scope.unselectedCell = [].

It's similar to that http://plnkr.co/edit/cCsLf6g83Xhg72mePoFf?p=preview.
But, it's based on the cursor pointer in <td element its only select. Not hole row and column.

Please see my implementation code from http://jsfiddle.net/q4wcgbLq/12/

Also, same functionality works or supports the mobile device.

But, I do not want to use jquery and jquery ui selectable functions and mouser-over and mouser-down events.

How does this type of functionality in Angular.js or is it possible in Angular.js?

I tried using mousedown and mouseup event but it's not working properly and does not support it on a mobile device it.

Any other way do this type functionality and also, work on mobile devices using angular Js

How I can achieve this? or please let me know.

I have implemented some code below jsfiddle.

In Viewhtml file

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="myselectctr"> 
    
<table class="cell-box-selection">
    <thead>
<tr>
<th ng-repeat="monlist in monthsarr">
    {{monlist}} 
</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

<tr>
        
        <td class="days-val">01</td>
<td ng-repeat="val in valindaysarr " class="mainbox_{{$index}} cellselect" ng-class="{'cellselect': cellbox{{$index}}, 'uncellselect': !cellbox{{$index}}}" ng-click="selectioncell($index)" datavalselet="{{val}}01">{{val}}01</td>
      
</tr>
    <tr>
        
        <td class="days-val">02</td>
<td ng-repeat="val in valindaysarr track by $index" class="mainbox_{{$index*1+7}} smallcell cellselect" ng-class="{'cellselect': cellbox{{$index*1+7}}, 'uncellselect': !cellbox{{$index*1+7}}}" ng-click="selectioncell($index*1+7)" datavalselet="{{val}}02">{{val}}02</td>
      
</tr>
     <tr>
        
        <td class="days-val">03</td>
<td ng-repeat="val in valindaysarr track by $index" class="mainbox_{{$index*1+14}} smallcell cellselect" ng-class="{'cellselect': cellbox{{$index*1+14}}, 'uncellselect': !cellbox{{$index*1+14}}}" ng-click="selectioncell($index*1+14)" datavalselet="{{val}}03">{{val}}03</td>
      
</tr>
    
</table>  
    </div>
    </div>
```

In Controller.js

```
function myselectctr($scope) {
    
    $scope.selectedCell = [];
    
    $scope.unselectedCell = [];
    
  
    $scope.monthsarr = ['M/D','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apri', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul'];
    
    $scope.dayscountarr = ['01','02','03','04', '05','06','07'];
    
    $scope.valindaysarr = ['jan','feb','mar','apri', 'may','jun','jul'];
    
    for(var i=0; i<49; i++){
        $scope.selectioncell = function(i){
                    $scope['cellbox'+i] = !$scope['cellbox'+i];
        }
    }

}
```

Can you please help me?